# Promise.all does not resolve promises as expected

Tags: typescript, promise

For some reason this works as expected:

```
  const metadatasExternal = await Promise.all(
    NFTs.map(n => axios.get(n.metadataOnchain?.data.uri!))
  )
```

But this doesn't:

```
  const metadatasExternal = await Promise.all(
    NFTs.map(n => ({
      metadataPDA: n.metadataPDA,
      metadataExternal: axios.get(n.metadataOnchain?.data.uri!),
    }))
  )
```

Specifically the promises aren't being resolved. This is what I get back:

```
  {
    metadataPDA: PublicKey {}
    metadataExternal: Promise { <pending> }
  },
```

Why is that? And how do I fix it? I specifically need to include the `metadataPDA` key in each promise, otherwise I can't match them to another data structure in the code.

Comment: Well, why should it? `axios.get` is the one that returns a promise. You've hidden away that promise inside an object key and it is never awaited. `Promise.all` expects an **array of promises** that it awaits on. Yet, you've given it an array of plain objects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to feed [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) an array of promises. In your second snippet, you feed it in an array of plain objects, with a promise in one of the keys. `Promise.all` doesn't know magic, and won't be able to await on the promises you've hidden away within said objects.

Instead, ensure you return promises within the `map`-

```
const metadatasExternal = await Promise.all(
    NFTs.map(async n => {
        const data = await axios.get(n.metadataOnchain?.data.uri!);
        return { metadataPDA: n.metadataPDA, metadataExternal: data };
    })
);
```